# NVD3 line chart having color gradients according to positive/negative values

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, html5-canvas, nvd3.js

I am having trouble on nvd3.
What i want is having color variations according to y values. .
Something like this : [image]

But the color should vary with the y axis. 
Example : If the y axis value is

**negative** - **red**,

**positive** - **green**

**neutral**  - **yellow**

This is the code for the similar for a normal line chart.

**css**

```
.line {                         
    fill: none;                 
    stroke: url(#line-gradient);    
    stroke-width: 2px;          
}
```

**JS:**

```
svg.append("linearGradient")                
        .attr("id", "line-gradient")            
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")    
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))         
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(1000))      
    .selectAll("stop")                      
        .data([                             
            {offset: "0%", color: "red"},       
            {offset: "40%", color: "red"},  
            {offset: "40%", color: "black"},        
            {offset: "62%", color: "black"},        
            {offset: "62%", color: "lawngreen"},    
            {offset: "100%", color: "lawngreen"}    
        ])                  
    .enter().append("stop")         
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })   
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });
```

I tried implementing the same on the nvd3 line chart js plugin files,but failed.

Is there any way to achieve this on the nvd3 line charts?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a fiddle of what you've done so far on NVD3 so far.

Comment: Am not sure if i can,it contains a lot of files. . (Meaning my project).
But Isnt it possible for you to insert the above piece of code into the lineWithFocusChart.js of nvd3.

Comment: although [this gist](https://gist.github.com/timelyportfolio/24aba58d942c2504d9bf) is for rCharts using nvd3, it might be helpful  .  it makes the lines dashed.  I would think it could be adapted to apply your gradient.

Comment: @timelyportfolio I went through that, and what it does is change the entire line's style to dashed.
My requirement is a bit different,have to put color gradients with percentage values.

Comment: not sure if you are locked into `nvd3`.  if not, would something like this from dimple work http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color

Comment: @timelyportfolio Thats what i want,but i have done my work on nvd3. . and shifting it to another chart library is gna be hard.